# rewrite model class

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

How to overwrite core model ? (what's wrong with below code?)

Trying to overwrite: `\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php`

```
//\app\code\local\Trening\Catalog\etc\config.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <category>Trening_Catalog_Model_Category</category>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>

//\app\code\local\Trening\Catalog\Model\Category.php
class Trening_Catalog_Model_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Category{
    public function getChildren()
    {
        echo 'overwrite';
    }
}

//\app\etc\modules\Trening_Catalog.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Trening_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Trening_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and below return original method:

```
$catal = Mage::getModel("Catalog/Category")->load(2);
var_dump($catal->getChildren());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call model like this:

```
$catal = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(2);
var_dump($catal->getChildren());
```

and change `getChildren()` method like this:

```
public function getChildren()
{
    return 'overwrite';
}
```

If you are still not getting the rewritten output, then you need to check following things:

- Make sure you removed all cache.
- Make sure any other modules are not rewriting the same class.

Other than these, I cannot see other issues with your module.

Comment: yes, `catalog/category` instead of `Catalog/Category` did a job. Thank You.